# SharePoint InfoPath multiple selection box

Tags: multiple-values

I am using two multiple selection box in site using using InfoPath. I have kept one in a section. Based on particular item selection in the other, section is visible or hidden. I am able to hide section using all occurences of value. But the problem is each time section is hidden, selections are not unchecked in the multiple selection. Please help.

Comment: you may want to use screenshot here to help us figure out your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming if any value in multi selection box is selected while it was visible and later if the conditions change such that the multi selection box gets hidden, the selected values are not getting unchecked (cleared).

Well if this is the problem, you need to do one more extra step, add new action rule under the hide/show formatting rule to clear the selected values in the multi selection box.